# How to read an online resource and update the popup in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to create my first Google Chrome Extension.

Any ideas why this is not copy pasting from the example.com website to my pop-up?

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('http://example.com'), false);
  xhr.send();
  document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
});
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="response"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Getting started",
  "description": "Display test from Example.com",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://example.com"
  ]
}
```

BTW, I'm not intending to inject captured content straight into my popup! (Script injecting etc.) At this stage, I'm just working out how everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues

1. You need to request permissions for any XMLHttp request you make, so that’s clearly labeled in your extension.   The way to do this is to list the websites you’re going to access in your manifest.son.  This is super simple and covered here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr
2. The request itself, when you send it, it doesn’t have an answer right away.  This is because it’s going over the internet and making your request in the background.  So you can’t ask for responseText straight after you call send - because it doesn’t know the answer yet.  You have to tell it to call you back on a function after it’s finished loading.  This is called a callback.
3. Debugging.  There is a tool you can install from Google to make “Inspect Element” work on your extension.  This means that you can right click on your dropdown and choose inspect element from the context menu.  Then you can flip to the console tab and see all your javascript errors.    https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc?hl=en

This also means you can sprinkle in console.log(“am here”) anywhere and you can see what’s getting called and what’s not...

Here's what I got working combining yours with the google sample.

Hope this helps!
JFo

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://www.example.com/"
  ]
}
```

Popup.js

```
// makeWebRequest
//
// ANY URLs you want to call with "makeWebRequest" need to be listed in your manifest.json
//    https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

//
// responseType 'json' 'document' 'text'
// callback is the function to call back on success. will be passed the XMLHttpRequest
// errorCallback is called when there's a problem

function makeWebRequest(urlToLoad, responseType, callback, errorCallback) {

  console.log("making web request for: "  + urlToLoad);

  var xmlReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlReq.open('GET', urlToLoad);
  // The Google image search API responds with JSON, so let Chrome parse it.
  xmlReq.responseType = responseType;
  xmlReq.onload = function() {
    // Parse and process the response from Google Image Search.
    var response = xmlReq.response;
   /// if (!response || !response.responseData || !response.responseData.results ||
    //    response.responseData.results.length === 0) {

    if (!xmlReq.response) {
       errorCallback('No response from the web request!');
       return;
    }


    callback(xmlReq);
  };
  xmlReq.onerror = function() {
    errorCallback('Network error.');
  };
  xmlReq.send();  // this goes away, makes the internet request, then calls back when it's finished.
}




// This is called when the extension loads.

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  // Response type:
  // use json for json, document for html documents, text for raw text

  makeWebRequest("http://www.example.com/index.html", "document", 
    function (xmlReq) {
        // this is the function that is called back on when "Send" finishes

        // returns an HTMLDocument because we passed the "document" 
        // responseType into makeWebRequest.
        var doc = xmlReq.response;

        console.log("web request finished " + xmlReq.response);

        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = doc.documentElement.innerHTML;
    }

  , function(errorMessage) {
        // this is the function that is called back on when there is an error 
        // requesting the file
        console.log("got error:" + errorMessage);

  });

});
```

Popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 400px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Sample extension
    <div id="status"></div>
    <p id="response"></p>
    <img id="image-result" hidden>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Code works. Now working my way through a Chrome Extension debugging tutorial based on the tool you linked me to.